# What if difficulty bomb makes mining impossible before POS release?

Tags: proof-of-stake, releases, difficulty-bomb

As mining difficulty raises and POS is still not ready, I was just wondering if POS release can still be on time compared to the difficulty bomb giving too high difficulty. In simpler words, is there a risk that difficulty become too high to mine before POS is ready and what would be the consequences? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difficult bomb was actually *added* in a hard fork shortly after Ethereum's launch. It's not a necessary part of the protocol, and so if PoS isn't ready on time, it's most likely that another hard fork will delay or remove the bomb. In fact, if a portion of the Ethereum community desires to still use PoW, or does not agree with the final PoS protocol, there will likely be a hard fork on the remaining PoW network to remove the bomb.

Comment: Note that I just wait to see if someone gives another answer but I will validate it soon.