# What are the mechanisms that use the Ethereum network to decide when a block B is done and we are going to mine block B+1?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blocks

I know from the [Ethereum Stats](https://ethstats.net/) that a block is mined on average within 14 secs. But that is only on average. I want to know, step by step if possible, what are he mechanisms to say "*okay, this block is done, let's create a new one*".

In my opinion, it is not a limit of block size (even if there is one), because the Ethereum network can adapt itself if transactions does not consume more than [3 141 592 gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size/1110#1110), which represent a lot of transactions.

So, I think this is related to the nounce which set the difficulty to have a block/12 secs. But I'm not sure about it.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, ethereum is a state machine. You have a database of states (for example accounts with amounts). How these states change? by via of transactions. Which can be `give X ether from A to B` to smart contracts invocations. OK, the transactions are grouped in a *block*. And here is where it gets interesting.

You have the universe of *miners* working on producing blocks. They take transactions from the pool, process them, until they reach the `gasLimit`, assigning to their designated account (called the `etherbase`) the *transaction fees* and the *reward* for block found in the end, and from here they produce a random *nonce*. The *nonce* is important: from this *nonce* and the *block* you made, you create a *hash*, complicated enough to make your machine *work* a lot (i.e. using a lot of CPU, memory and energy. That's why it's called *Proof of work*). Once the miner has a *hash*, this is compared to the *target*, which is no other than `2**256 / Difficulty`, so the greater the difficulty, the lesser the odds of finding a hash lesser than the target.

Since you can produce randomly `2**256` possible hashes, from your *block* made and your *nonce*, your probability at any moment of finding a valid hash is `1/D`. The first miner able to find a *hash* lesser than the *target*, propagates its result. If the other miners get this block, and find it *valid* (by replaying its transactions and verifying nonce and *hash*), it is incorporated in their respective *blockchain*.

Now, the question: How do they manage to reach about 14 seconds in average? Well, there is a [difficulty calculation function](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c04c8f10f04a41e762589358418c65fd99891bb4/core/block_validator.go#L273-L320) (see [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5914/1281) for an outstanding explanation of it), that every time a block is made, is recalculated. Then, you see that based on what you take to produce the last block, you adjust the difficulty to be able to reach a time between `10` and `19` seconds. Of course this difficulty is validated along the new block too.

To answer your question, in the end, the `difficulty` is related to data from the *parent block*, namely the *difficulty*, *block number* and *time* of this *parent*, and the *time* of the *current block*.

Comment: Note that miners are profit maximizers, and the work to make a block with 0 transactions is the same in probabilistic terms to the work of making a block with the maximum transactions permitted by the system (`gasLimit`). They will want to include as much transactions as possible to get the tx fees.