# Difficulty growing exponentially with block chain length?

Tags: yellow-paper

The [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) includes on page 6 in equation (44) a term [image: \epsilon] which contributes to the difficulty of a block. This term is added to the difficulty in equation (39).

[image: equation]

[image: \epsilon] is an exponential function which depends on the length of the block chain only. The longer the chain up to the current block [image: H_i], the higher [image: \epsilon] and [image: \epsilon] is growing exponentially.

This looks very strange. It would mean that the longer the chain, the higher the difficulty and the more difficult and costly it becomes to mine a new block. This is counter intuitive.

Does [image: \epsilon] really depend on the length of the block chain? Or is this a typo on in the paper and should it actually depend on something else, i.e. the gas limit [image: H_l] instead of the chain length [image: H_i]?

Answer (score 4):

That portion of the difficulty adjustment formula is the difficulty bomb that will make mining proof-of-work increasingly more difficult to force miners to move to a proof-of-stake network.

Further information in the following Q&As:

- [What is the "difficulty bomb" and what is the goal of it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/323/what-is-the-difficulty-bomb-and-what-is-the-goal-of-it)
- [When will the difficulty bomb make mining impossible?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/when-will-the-difficulty-bomb-make-mining-impossible)
- [What if difficulty bomb makes mining impossible before POS release?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/what-if-difficulty-bomb-makes-mining-impossible-before-pos-release)
- [How does the Ethereum Homestead difficulty adjustment algorithm work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/how-does-the-ethereum-homestead-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-work)